# Weird inheritance in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I've been poking into some Node.js modules in the hopes of learning something I could have missed while creating a module with similar functionality. Then I came across this code from [Hound](https://github.com/beefsack/node-hound):

```
function Hound() {
    //why this?
    events.EventEmitter.call(this)
}

//ok, so inheriting the EventEmitter
util.inherits(Hound, events.EventEmitter);
```

I know that the `util.inherits()` function from Node.js creates a new Parent instance as the prototype of the child constructor [as stated in the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor):

> The prototype of constructor will be set to a new object created from superConstructor.

So if our constructor is inheriting `EventEmitter` through `util.inherits()`, what is that code in the constructor for?

Comment: I've seen this type of thing around from time to time. I always assumed it was needed to call the super constructor explicitly on the instance being constructed. Given that excerpt from the docs though, I'm not sure if it's necessary or not. Maybe it's an old convention left-over from when `inherits` worked differently?

Comment: it's not bad code; JavaScript doesn't have all the inheritance niceties of other languages.  This is simply how node.js expects you to work with the EventEmitter class.

Comment: Macek is right. `util.inherits` sets up the prototype, and calling the constructor sets up the instance. This pattern is used all over in node's core libraries: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just making your `Hound` class an `EventEmitter` object.

It gives your the [EventEmitter instance methods](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to the class.

E.g., `houndInstance.emit('something')`

Other objects that are listening to these events can then respond to them.

---

Per your comment:

```
// constructor
function Hound() {

    // equivalent of calling a "super" or "parent" constructor
    SomeClass.call(this);
}
```

In JavaScript, `.call(context)` is a means of invoking a function in a specific context.  In the example above, we're just calling the `SomeClass` constructor and passing `this` (the `Hound` class in this example) as the context.

Comment: But doesn't `util.inherits()` already cover that? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

From your comments:

> But doesn't util.inherits() already cover that? Or am I missing something?

What you are missing is that `util.inherits()` merely inherits the parent object. It doesn't set up the constructor to automatically call the parent object's constructor. In most cases it would be enough since most objects don't do much initialization in their constructors.

But `events.EventEmitter` apparently does some initialization in the constructor that has some important side effects. Since prototypical inheritance does not automatically call the parent's constructor you need to call it manually in this case. Hence the `events.EventEmitter.call(this)` line.

---

Note that an alternative is to use the module pattern which always calls the parent's constructor. That is because the module pattern is not inheritance per-se but emulates inheritance by abusing the mixin/decorator pattern - it creates an object from the parent constructor and manually add attributes to it. Lots of people don't like the module pattern because it duplicates functions and attrubutes - hence they see it as wasting memory. Also, it's not proper inheritance and so breaks stuff like `instanceof`.